# Best way to broadcast information to Wi-Fi enabled devices?

Tags: wifi, apk, p2p, wireless, wifi-direct

I live in a building where the laundry machine is a bit far away from my suite. There is only one machine there so only one person can use it at a time. Quite often I take my laundry there just to realize that the machine is in use so I have to go back defeated and try again later. I want to build a doodad that can detect when the machine is in use and broadcast that information throughout the building so that I know that the machine will be available before I go there.

This question is not about how to build the detector. I am planning on using a raspberry pi somehow. This question is about what do I do when I detect that the machine is in use. How do I broadcast that information mainly to myself or potentially to anyone in the building?

I need a cheap solution (< $100). It has to be wireless. The signal has to travel approximately 30 meters in one direction. The broadcast should be readable on any laptop or cell phone (not a requirement but nice to have).

I was considering making an android app using WiFi direct. I'm sure others in the building would be interested in this app and I can use them as peers to extend the range of the broadcast. But I don't like this solution because I know that wifi direct doesn't work with iOS devices. Also this solution will require others to side-load an apk which they might not know how to do.

Please let me know if you can come up with something a bit less reliant on p2p and more platform independent.